# How to get notification immediately after saving the image in folder?

Tags: php, jquery, server

I am doing an app in which have to get notification(local) when image is save d into a folder in server.Is it possible to start running script after getting notification?Can anyone please help me in this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(move_uploaded_file($temporary, $upload_location)) 
{
   echo "<span style='font-size:0px'>image_saved</span>";
}
```

if you are using jquery then you can grab the response from php and show it on your app..

```
if(indexOf('image_saved') != -1){
    $('#messageDisplayer').html("The image has been saved successfully");
}
else{
    //do something
}
```